# How to delete document from firestore using where clause

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
var jobskill_ref = db.collection('job_skills').where('job_id','==',post.job_id);
jobskill_ref.delete();
```

**Error thrown**

> jobskill_ref.delete is not a function

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can only delete a document once you have a `DocumentReference` to it. To get that you must first execute the query, then loop over the `QuerySnapshot` and finally delete each `DocumentSnapshot` based on its `ref`.

```
var jobskill_query = db.collection('job_skills').where('job_id','==',post.job_id);
jobskill_query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ref.delete();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Not sure what the options here are .. maybe this is NodeJS? .. in my case with web JS and had to make the call with **get().** followed by **.then()** like so: `.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {}`

Comment: Thanks for posting an improved answer. My answer focusses on the fact that you need to first execute a query before you can delete its results (individually.)  It's great to see that you found a way to improve my approach for your context, and thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @OliverDixon from what I can tell, Frank called out the key requirements for deleting a range of documents which answers OPs question (eg. 'delete where')... anything else can be adapted by the engineer to fit their needs.

It's awesome that you added an answer which might help someone else with your specific use in Firebase Functions... since the user didn't specifically call out Firebase Functions it might make your response _less_ approachable - especially since it's using some unique ES2017/TS features.

Oh, and just an FYI that Frank is a respected Firebase Engineer. 

Comment: I can't say I didn't try! ‍♂️ You might consider the number of votes this answer has compared to yours in your analysis. To be clear, I didn't say your code _only_ applies to Firebase Functions, but you specifically called it out in your comments here and in your answer. Compare that to Frank's answer which called out the key requirements for a 'delete where' and gave an example that the user could adapt to their needs. Lazy copy-paste is an issue... but Frank's answer explained WHY the user needed to do something... your answer just provided a different code approach w/ no explanation. 

Comment: Also just a note, return the function so that it's flagged on your logs if there is ever an error.

Answer (score 50):

I use [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) for this. For example:

```
var jobskill_ref = db.collection('job_skills').where('job_id','==',post.job_id);
let batch = firestore.batch();

jobskill_ref
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });
    return batch.commit();
  })
```

ES6 async/await:

```js
const jobskills = await store
  .collection('job_skills')
  .where('job_id', '==', post.job_id)
  .get();

const batch = store.batch();

jobskills.forEach(doc => {
  batch.delete(doc.ref);
});

await batch.commit();
```

Comment: be aware that `A batched write can contain up to 500 operations`, so additional logic may be needed, depending on the number of documents

Comment: Without running loop, how can we perform this solution? kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

```
//The following code will find and delete the document from firestore

const doc = await this.noteRef.where('userId', '==', userId).get();
doc.forEach(element => {
    element.ref.delete();
    console.log(`deleted: ${element.id}`);
});
```

Comment: can you do the deletion using batch? because deleting doc by doc is not optimal one.

Comment: Not sure you will have to try that.

Comment: @astroboy how can we delete using batch, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

the key part of Frank's answer that fixed my issues was the `.ref` in `doc.ref.delete()`

**I originally only had `doc.delete()` which gave a "not a function" error.** now my code looks like this and works perfectly:

```
let fs = firebase.firestore();
let collectionRef = fs.collection(<your collection here>);

collectionRef.where("name", "==", name)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.delete().then(() => {
      console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });
  });
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

Comment: The key here being that you use `.ref.delete()`

Comment: This won't catch errors though? It won't wait for the Foreach iterator to finish.

Answer (score 3):

or try this, but you must have the id beforehand

```
export const deleteDocument = (id) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection("contracts")
    .doc(id)
    .delete()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("DC").delete().then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I resolved this is by giving each document a uniqueID, querying on that field, getting the documentID of the returned document, and using that in the delete. Like so:

(Swift)

```
func rejectFriendRequest(request: Request) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.db.collection("requests")
            .whereField("uniqueID", isEqualTo: request.uniqueID)
            .getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
                if let e = error {
                    print("There was an error fetching that document: \(e)")
                } else {
                    self.db.collection("requests")
                        .document(querySnapshot!.documents.first!.documentID)
                        .delete() { err in
                            if let e = err {
                                print("There was an error deleting that document: \(e)")
                            } else {
                                print("Document successfully deleted!")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The code could be cleaned up a bit, but this is the solution I came up with. Hope it can help someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const firestoreCollection = db.collection('job_skills')

var docIds = (await firestoreCollection.where("folderId", "==", folderId).get()).docs.map((doc => doc.id))

// for single result
await firestoreCollection.doc(docIds[0]).delete()

// for multiple result

await Promise.all(
  docIds.map(
    async(docId) => await firestoreCollection.doc(docId).delete()
  )
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

And of course, you can use await/async:

```
exports.delete = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
try {
    var jobskill_ref = db.collection('job_skills').where('job_id','==',post.job_id).get();
    jobskill_ref.forEach((doc) => {
      doc.ref.delete();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.json({
      status: 'error', msg: 'Error while deleting', data: error,
    });
  }
});
```

I have no idea why you have to **get()** them and **loop** on them, then **delete()** them, while you can prepare one query with where to delete in one step like any SQL statement, but Google decided to do it like that. so, for now, this is the only option.

Comment: Without running loop, how can we perform this solution? kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cloud Firestore on the Client side, you can use a Unique key generator package/module like uuid to generate an ID. Then you set the ID of the document to the ID generated from uuid and store a reference to the ID on the object you're storing in Firestore.

For example:
If you wanted to save a person object to Firestore, first, you'll use uuid to generate an ID for the person, before saving like below.

```js
const uuid = require('uuid') 

const person = { name: "Adebola Adeniran", age: 19}
const id = uuid() //generates a unique random ID of type string
const personObjWithId = {person, id} 

export const sendToFireStore = async (person) => {
  await db.collection("people").doc(id).set(personObjWithId);
};

// To delete, get the ID you've stored with the object and call // the following firestore query

export const deleteFromFireStore = async (id) => {
  await db.collection("people").doc(id).delete();
};
```

Hope this helps anyone using firestore on the Client side.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the question asked. Plus Firebase will auto-generate document id's for you so no need to import an extra module/package to handle that seperately.

Answer (score -2):

```
delete(seccion: string, subseccion: string) 
{
 const deletlist = this.db.collection('seccionesclass', ref => ref.where('seccion', '==', seccion).where('subseccion', '==' , subseccion))
deletlist.get().subscribe(delitems => delitems.forEach( doc=> doc.ref.delete()));
    alert('record erased');
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: using `delete` as a function name is not encouraged, as `delete` is a JS keyword. It's used to delete a property from an object. Example: `const o = {a: 1}; delete o[a]`