# Deleting Specific element in firestore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a document in the database. I'm retrieving the document by the following command:

```
doc_ref = db
    .collection(u'items')
    .where(u'Name', u'==', str(Name))
    .where(u'ID', u'==', str(ID))
    .stream()
```

i understand this is a query and it does not have an id unless its the document but not sure how to solve this. They way Google's documentation has it is that you need:

```
db.collection(u'cities').document(u'DC').delete()
```

But i'm not sure what is the correct syntax to use the document obtained above. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified by an Engineer from Google in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180442/12767257), first, you will need to execute the query to retrieve the values, then loop over the "snapshot" from the database generated, and finally delete each document from the "snapshot".

So, first you will need to perform your query to retrieve the values, using that query that you are already using and then run the below code:

```
for doc in doc_ref:
    print(u'Deleting doc {} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
    doc.reference.delete()
```

**This code is untested**, however, I believe it's a good starting point, since I got it from the official documentation, accessible [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections). This code should go through the stream you created and delete each document.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been scratching my head over this for a while  and did not notice the ```.reference```! It had an issue where it turns everything in that collection to null but now it works. Probably the way i reference it. Thanks again!

Comment: That's great @STOPIMACODER ! I'm glad to hear that I could help you and everything is fine now!