# Firebase Firestore Delete multiple documents by timestamp and more fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I see a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180076/how-to-delete-document-from-firestore-using-where-clause) . However, I am very new to coding and I am trying to delete all the documents that are older than 1 month and not premium from the “users” collection. When deleting a document, the “user_online” filed need to be 30 days or more old and “user_premium” need to be “no”.

I am using the node js with adminsdk.

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me with a node js code to achieve above.

[image]

using some other post I came up with following.

```
var userdelete_query = db.collection('users').where('user_online', '<=', new Date(Date.now() - 2592000000) && 'user_premium', '==', 'no');
userdelete_query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ref.delete();
    console.log(`deleted: ${doc.id}`);
  });
});
```

above code shows no errors, but nothing happens. I think the following part is the problem

```
&& 'user_premium', '==', no); -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine two where clauses, you need to chain them, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

```
var userdelete_query = db.collection('users')
.where('user_online', '<=', new Date(Date.now() - 2592000000))
.where('user_premium', '==', 'no');

userdelete_query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ref.delete();
  });
});
```

Note that you will need to create a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for this query to work.

---

Note that with the above code you don't know when all the docs are deleted. If you want to monitor the execution of all the parallel calls to the `delete()` method, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
const userdelete_query = db.collection('users')
.where('user_online', '<=', new Date(Date.now() - 2592000000))
.where('user_premium', '==', 'no');

userdelete_query.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
  const promises = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    promises.push(doc.ref.delete());
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
})
.then(function() {
  console.log("ALL DOCS ARE DELETED");
})
```

---

A third possible approach would be to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) (or better, a batched deletion).