# React Native Firestore document deletion

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run the code below, but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
await followRequestsColl.doc()
        .where('Followed', '==', user.uid)
        .where('Following', '==', targetUserUid)
        .delete().then(() => {
          console.log('User deleted!');
        });
```

**Error :** Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6):
TypeError: followRequestsColl.doc().where is not a function. (In 'followRequestsColl.doc().where('Followed', '==', user.uid)', 'followRequestsColl.doc().where'
is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You should only search in collections:

```
await followRequestsColl.collection('somecollectionname')
    .where('Followed', '==', user.uid)
    .where('Following', '==', targetUserUid)
    .delete().then(() => {
      console.log('User deleted!');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to RobrechtVMs observation that you can't query a document. you also can't call `delete()` on a query.

You will have to:

1. Execute the query
2. Loop over the results
3. Delete each document in turn

Something like:

```
const query = followRequestsColl.collection('somecollectionname')
  .where('Followed', '==', user.uid)
  .where('Following', '==', targetUserUid);
query.get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.delete();
  })
})
```

Also see: [How to delete document from firestore using where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180076/how-to-delete-document-from-firestore-using-where-clause/47180442#47180442)