# How do you delete a document using where in Angular Fire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

```
var doc = this.afs.collection('/documents', ref => ref.where('docID', '==', docID));
```

Using the above code i get the document the user wants successfully, however not sure on how to then delete that document.
I have tried the obvious .doc().delete(), however that needs a path for the doc itself.

is there a way to delete all documents (1) from this query and delete them

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to do this deletion via AngularFire? You can also do it via the JavaScript SDK, and in that case it is covered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180076/how-to-delete-document-from-firestore-using-where-clause/47180442#47180442. AngularFire will pick up such deletes through the regular SDK automatically.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen currently running the app, without any Restful API, almost using cloud functions as an API, would you say running it as a cloud function to be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `const db = this.afs.firestore` and then do what Frank describes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180442/6002078).

Comment: This feels cleaner to me than angularfire's way, because angularfire revolves around Observables and Subscriptions (streams of data), when all you want is "get stuff once => delete stuff".

If you wanted to "observe" that query and delete any document that appears in the future, the situation would be different.

Comment: Awesome thanks heaps!
Yeah would you probably consider angular fire more of an add on than a full adaptation and wrapper for firebase

Comment: AngularFire is a wrapper around the Firebase JavaScript SDK to make it easier to show results from Firebase in your Angular UIs. When writing to the database, I often find it easier to work with the JavaScript SDK directly. And since AngularFire wraps that SDK, they interop perfectly.